# Linux axel write error

Tags: linux, download

I was downloading a 4.0 GB file using axel. When it reached 98%, it displayed "Write Error". I still have 30+ GB of free disk space.

I tried to run axel again, and got "Write Error" again. Here is the actual display:

```
State file found: 4251724925 bytes downloaded, 62428035 to go.
Starting download

,,,,,,,,,, ,,,,,,,,,, ,,,,,.....


Write error!

Downloaded 5.0 kilobytes in 0 seconds. (0.00 KB/s)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is axel http://axel.alioth.debian.org/? Is this over http? Have you tried with a different download client, say wget? `wget -c` has the advantage of being restartable.

Comment: I'm using Gentoo. Ang I installed axel using the emerge feature of Gentoo so I have no idea where axel came from. Anyway, I am certain that it is over http. I will try wget if this issue cannot be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Does axel support restartable downloads? Also, your package manager may show the home page. With Debian, `apt-cache show axel` shows the page. In any case, I expect it is the same project. Yes, I'd give `wget` a try if applicable.

Comment: On experience, download continues when I restart axel from which it ended from.

Comment: You could give the axel mailing lists a try. If the file is publicly downloadable. I recommend you submit a bug report.

Comment: yes, if the issue cannot be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version are you using? You might have been hit by [this bug](http://alioth.debian.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=311324) if the version you've installed is too old to include its patch.

Comment: I was using 2.3. I have just downloaded 2.4 and it worked very fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FAT32 has a 4Gbyte limit for files.  If you're saving this to a FAT32 partition or flash drive this could be an issue.

Comment: The partition saved is actually ext3. Will that bear same issue? How to solve it?